# Strange Internet Explorer and Firefox CSS Problem

Tags: css, firefox, explorer

A friend of mine ask me for help, but I'am not able to spot the mistake.
It's about:
http://www.nachhilfe-hh.de/nachhilfe-hamburg-west.php

The problem is that the phone image is getting cutted and the text is overlapping with Internet Explorer. Firefox works fine. I analysed the CSS with Firebug and found out that there was a missing "< /div >". That solved a problem, but not the ones with the image.
If I try to change width of the image: Not happens.
If I try to change position of the text: Either the appearance sucks in IE or Firefox.
And changing "< div >" to "< span >" is also causing no effect.

Does someone have an idea? Pls?

Answer (score 1):

`.telefoncontainer` got a `width:329px` and the picture got one of 370px.

It works on other browser because `.telefoncontainer p`'s width is good. But IE ignore children's width to resize the parent's one.

Answer (score 1):

First off: There is still a `</div>` missing: http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.nachhilfe-hh.de%2Fnachhilfe-hamburg-west.php

I'd suggest to avoid `position: relative`. It the reason for the overlapping, and even if you find the error in this case, it can lead to more overlapping in other places.

Simplify the HTML for the telefoncontainer to:

```
<div class="telefoncontainer">
   <div id="stadt">Nachhilfe Hamburg West</div>
   <div id="telefon">040 / 839 75 03</div>
</div>
```

(All the extra, `p`s, `div`s and `center` are unnecessary).

And then just adjust the `padding` of the container, until the content are positioned correctly.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/sVhd2/

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using a conditional comment to target IE specifically? this will allow you to have different styles for each browser, so a change in one shouldn't break the other. See: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html for a good run-through of the capabilities and usage of these

Comment: I don't think using Conditional Comments are the solution for bad HTML and CSS.

Comment: true, though it doesn't hurt to let him know about them